# how to merge rows in data frame to have one row per unique id in R

Tags: r

I created a data set with rank variables that looks something like this:

[image]

I want to merge the rank1 , rank2 and rank3 value by the UniqueID and Predictor columns so that the data set looks something like the following:

[image]

I am kind of lost on how to perform this in R. I tried using the aggregate and group_by functions but I am not being able to achieve my desired output. Is there a way to obtain the output I want in R? Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `library(dplyr); df1 %>% group_by(UniqueID, Predictor) %>% summarise_all(funs(if(all(.==0)) 0 else .[.!=0]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that we need to ignore 0's if there are values greater than 0, after grouping by 'UniqueID', 'Predictor', use `summarise_all` and specify the condition to return 0 if `all` the values are 0 or `else` return the value that is not 0.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(UniqueID, Predictor) %>%
    summarise_all(funs(if(all(.==0)) 0L else as.integer(.[.!=0])))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups: UniqueID [?]
#  UniqueID Predictor rank1 rank2 rank3
#  <chr>    <chr>     <int> <int> <int>
#1 ID1      1             2     1     0
#2 ID2      1             1     0     1
#3 ID3      0             1     0     0
```

NOTE: The assumption is that there are not more than 2 rows for each 'UniqueID'.  If there are multiple unique elements other than 0, place it in a `list` or `paste` to create a string

---

If there are more than one unique value other than 0

```
df1 %>%
    group_by(UniqueID, Predictor) %>%
    summarise_all(funs(if(all(.==0)) "0" else toString(unique(.[.!=0]))))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(UniqueID = c('ID1', 'ID1', 'ID2', 'ID2', 'ID3'),
   Predictor = c('1', '1', '1', '1', '0'), rank1 = c(0, 2, 0, 1, 1),
     rank2 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0), rank3 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I tried but is is giving me the following error: "Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : expecting a single value." Also there might be more than 2 rows for each Unique ID in some cases and all the ranks can have values ranging from 0,1,2,3.

Comment: @adda.fuentes  Try it on the data I showed.  You posted only an image of the example data.  Looks like you have more than one unique value other than 0.  In that case you may need `toString(unique(.[. !=0]))`

Comment: @adda.fuentes  Updated the post taking that into consideration